# Bitmap in org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, background-color, mapsforge

I used this code for showing a text on the map :

```
org.mapsforge.core.graphics.Bitmap bitmap=null;
            bitmap=     AndroidGraphicFactory.convertToBitmap(textAsBitmap(String.valueOf(VehicleCode1), 45, Color.BLACK));
            bitmap.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

if I remove this line:

```
  bitmap.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

on the map I see text but I want a yellow background under The text,
when I add this line:

```
 bitmap.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

I see only yellow rectangle on the map.
But I want a yellow rectangle with Text.
what should I do? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

maybe setting the color before initalizing the text. (u know, maybe the app is applying the text and after tht is overlaying it with the color)